# Run Command "Dir <drive:\path> /-c /o:GN /S >C:\path\textfile.txt" from within VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, directory, command

I have looked at several example snippets of code that users have been discussing and tried several but with no success.   The BV application I am trying this on has OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog added from the toolbox in Visual Studio Community.

For the most part I can access and select paths and files that I want  to interact with all fine.     However I wanted to run the command line statement in the title of this thread where I can programmatically select the Drive:\ and Path and the textfile.txt filename with in the VB app.

I do not need to see the command line console opening, but I think I am getting things wrong as I suspect windows expects certain things to be setup and exceptions to perhaps be captured that I simply don't have a grasp of.

If some kind soul has an example bit of code that I could use I would be most grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Note: Removed _shell_ Tag, since the question does not refer to POSIX or Bourne shell.

Comment: You stated what you _technically_ want to do. Run the DIR command with certain parameters, dumping the result in a text file. But what is your actual goal? If you want to programmatically retrieve a list of files, look at [System.IO.Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-8.0), [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-8.0) and [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-8.0). No need to shell to a CMD command for that.

Comment: The path doesn't belong in the title. That's an implantation detail. Also, you need to show us what you did and tell us what happened.

Comment: Look at using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8.1  with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: This seems like an AI generated post.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an answer, I did find a way using this in a subroutine.  I hope it help another lost soul like I was.

```
Sub Do_dir_to_file()
        Dim execute As String
        Dim p As New Process
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        Dim Dirpath As String
        Dim objFolderDlg As System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
        objFolderDlg = New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
        objFolderDlg.SelectedPath = "C:\"
        If objFolderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'MessageBox.Show(objFolderDlg.SelectedPath)
            Dirpath = objFolderDlg.SelectedPath
        End If
        '
        execute = """Dir """ + Dirpath + """ /-C /O:GN /s >C:\Tre\tdir.txt"""
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        pi.UseShellExecute = False
        pi.RedirectStandardInput = True
        pi.Arguments = "/C " + execute          
        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()
end Sub
```